# Mailgun - Campaign links timeout?

Tags: mailgun

I'm trying to use a Mailgun Campaign to help track emails sent through Mailgun. The links in the email get modified, as expected, so that Mailgun can collect stats on which links are getting clicked. However, the links are timing out.

Some of the clicks are definitely getting through (they are collected by Mailgun's Campaign tracking), but I'm also getting a lot of user reports of timeouts. Every time I try the links they timeout.

The Mailgun Domain and DNS Verification is all green, including the optional entries.

'Is it down' type services all says it's up: http://currentlydown.com/email.mg.dr2dr.ca

DNS resolution works, when I ping email.mg.dr2dr.ca, it resolves, but the requests all timeout.

I have started a ticket with Mailgun Support, but it's email support so I figured I would ask here to see if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: We are having the same problem right now, and it just happened over night. What happened in your case?

Comment: Did you figure out what happened in your case? The same problem with mailgun tracking links currently.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The best Mailgun support gave us was that the links look right and should be working.... but we found that the links only worked for  users using Firefox. We ended up giving up on using the campaign links.

Comment: Turned out for us that we had HSTS enabled on our Mailgun domain which Mailgun doesn't support. We had to purchase a new domain name to use with Mailgun without HSTS enabled.

Comment: Turned out for us that we had HSTS enabled on our Mailgun domain which Mailgun doesn't support. We had to purchase a new domain name to use with Mailgun without HSTS enabled.

Comment: Turned out for us that we had HSTS enabled on our Mailgun domain which Mailgun doesn't support. We had to purchase a new domain name to use with Mailgun without HSTS enabled.